# Jenkins SSLHandshakeException while publishing to confluence

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, confluence

We recently changed all the certificates and Jenkins seems to have been affected by that. It is unable to publish to confluence and it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Publisher com.myyearbook.hudson.plugins.confluence.ConfluencePublisher aborted due to exception
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

We use self signed certificates for our internal services. I added the new certificate into the trust store of the server running jenkins using the keytool command. The problem persist.
I am unable to track the source of the problem now.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
SanZig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was a problem with the location of the trusted keystore.
It's better to always add the certificates into the /var/lib/jenkins/.keystore rather than adding in the PATH_TO_JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts. If you still want to add the certificate into the cacerts then an ARG should be added in the application's config file:

JAVA_ARGS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts"

Sometimes you may need to add the certificate in ~/.keystore