# Certificate check Jenkins & TFS

Tags: tfs, jenkins, visual-studio-2013, hudson

I am integrating TFS and Jenkins. Useing TFS plugin. When I trigger build, it creates work_space and update it, and give below error about certificate.

any ideas!!!

Couple of attempts..

1 tried it on different machine = same error.
2. installed "skip certificate check" plug-in = got same error.
3. restarted machine after installation = no help :-(

======

All files are up to date.

```
    FATAL: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:99)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:23)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:70)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationData(RegistrationClient.java:645)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntry(RegistrationClient.java:188)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntry(RegistrationClient.java:167)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.webservices.IdentityManagementService.(IdentityManagementService.java:65)
       at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getVCCHistory(Project.java:84)
       at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getDetailedHistory(Project.java:128)
       at hudson.plugins.tfs.actions.CheckoutAction.checkout(CheckoutAction.java:56)
       at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:176)
       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1254)
       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234) 
    Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:744)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:473)
       at ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:105)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:65) ... 16 more 
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:597)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2518)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1313)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:508)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:588) ... 19 more 
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
       at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.internal.DefaultX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(DefaultX509TrustManager.java:181)
       at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source) ... 37 more 
    Caused by: 
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When using Team Explorer Everywhere, we set the TF_ACCEPT_UNTRUSTED_CERTIFICATES env variable to 1. Maybe it will help in your case as well.

Comment: Hi Johann, set TF_ACCEPT_UNTRUSTED_CERTIFICATES=1 also to true but still not working. Tried TFS accessing from internet explorer, it is working fine when use https:// and does not work when use http://. is there any way i can certificate manually to jenkins. because TFS works from IE with https://. greatly appreciate you help !!

Comment: It's a matter of the jre [needing to see the cacerts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23141658/598141)